# Статистика по трафику

Tags: nginx, статистика, трафик

Имеется видеохостинг который раздает видео с помощью iframe кода. Сайты берут себе данный код на страницу и у них отображается плеер с видео.
Встал вопрос реализации статистики по каждому сайту сколько трафика они используют.
Может есть готовые решения для данного вопроса.
Сервер на котором находится видеохостинг CentosOS.
Видео находятся на CDN

Comment: Готовых решений куча. Например, можно использовать django-request

Comment: а что бы вы сказали по поводу ntopng?

Comment: По описанию подходит. Сам лично не пробывал. :) Я лично использую то что выше (при тонкой настройке с токенами и.т.д.)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответ, но мой уровень знаний не позволяет использовать ваш вариант(

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, надёжного способа нет, в общем случае вы не сможете определить, это на самом деле iframe с такого-то сайта или же пользователь подделал HTTP-заголовки, чтобы вы думали, что это такой-то сайт

Comment: Дело в том, что статистика по показам есть (внутри самого движка) от теперь еще бы статистику по трафику как-то узнать, а переделывать они не будут, так как это им не нужно будет.